# How to produce maps with copyright imagery on it in GRASS?

Tags: grass-gis, cartography, printing, imagery

I'm having some trouble with a GIS that I've got to produce.

I work for a contractor and we'll have to produce maps to do the work for our client. The client has specified that if we print maps out (which we will have to) they will have to have various images on - the client's logo, map provider's logo, copyright information etc. We do have maps provided for us in PDF which have these logos on but they are an absolute pain to use, zoom in to a decent scale and keep the logos on. Using a GIS like GRASS would be much easier.

I'm new to GRASS and haven't found the option to add images to printouts yet. I've been messing around with the Cartographic Composer but haven't managed to find the option to add images - just text or automatically-generated content like legends.

Can anyone tell me where to look, or whether later versions of GRASS have this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rashad's method is good if you can get to the new Composer in GRASS.  If not, you can take advantage of QGIS' GRASS plugin.  The new 2.0.1 version of QGIS has an updated print composer that allows you to integrate your map data with images rather easily, plus the GRASS plugin lets you keep your data in its native GRASS format.

Comment: I eventually got GRASS working properly, but it was too inflexible for my needs (only one raster map? Most maps I produce have a few dozen in a tiled format). Now downloaded QGIS which works fine - just need it to update the extent each time I use the Print Composer. Failing that I'll have to tell the people using it to do it themselves - won't be too much trouble.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the images in Cartographic Composer in grass 6.4

```
File -> Cartographic Composer
```

Click on `Add Map Elements` button near the pencil icon. (see image below). You need to add your map first

[image: Add Image or logo]

Comment: I don't have the pencil icon (using 6.4.2). Could it be something to do with Python? Whenever I start the cartographic composer it says the Imaging library isn't available and that preview functionality won't work. Though as I say, I'm still missing the pencil icon. I do have the Map Elements, but that doesn't contain an Image. Also, how would I add the map? Is that the Map Frame? And what if my map has more than one raster/vector (told you I'm new!).

Comment: Hmm... may be that there's a newer version of 6.4 which will do the job. My Cartographic Composer still reads "experimental prototype". May try installing new version.

Comment: You need to install the "Python Imaging Library" (necessary for wxGUI Cartographic Composer), from http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil or it may be called "python-pillow".

Comment: See also http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/WxGUI_Cartographic_Composer

Comment: Seems everyone above was right, so wins for all! Huzzah! HeyOverThere may also have been right but I haven't tested it (I just downloaded a slightly newer version of GRASS - 6.4.3 rather than 6.4.2 which now has the image function). Now I just need to know how to actually use this thing.